# C# UWP Windows 10 Inter Process Communication with MemoryMappedFiles missing

Tags: c#, shared-memory, win-universal-app, memory-mapped-files, uwp

I'm facing a new problem, that occured while coding my IPC for my app.

Before UWP I was able to use the directive `using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;` sucessfully. Now I can't use `using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;` and I need it.

Is everyone facing the same issue? If yes, how do you solved it?

My app doesn't compile anymore.

I already tried to reimport the System.Core.dll as a reference and with DllImport, neither worked.

Answer (score 10):

Direct inter-process communication is not available in Universal apps.

You can use [App Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187314.aspx) or [LaunchUriForResultsAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt269386.aspx) to perform tasks that span multiple apps.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I'm not sure about how App Services work.
I have to create an AppServiceProvider and then my two or more apps, is that right ?

Comment: Yes, that is right. The App Services documentation is pretty detailed, and you can also take a look at the samples for more information: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServices

Comment: This answer isn't valid anymore, I have updated guide with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Support for `MemoryMappedFiles` in uwp was added while back.](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/commit/68949506e38203500c768fd2debbff73c0304b26) Although the documentation isn't clear, you can create and share `MemoryMappedFiles` using the directive `using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles`. You have to declare `codeGeneration` [capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#:%7E:text=Capabilities%20are%20used%20by%20UWP%20apps%20as%20well,by%20declaring%20capabilities%20in%20your%20app%27s%20package%20manifest.) to be able to do that.