# How to pass real time data quickly between two UWP apps?

Tags: uwp, ipc

I am trying to pass real time video (essentially byte arrays) received in one UWP app to another UWP app to display it.

I have been using [app services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to communicate between my two apps, but app services does not seem to designed for transferring large amounts of data quickly.

Is there a better way to pass large amounts of data between two UWP apps?

([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32707236/1438809) says no, but hopefully things have changed since then.)

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to pass data between two UWP apps. The first one is app services you are using. It is a common way used to transfer data.

If the publisher of both apps is you, maybe you could use the mechanism that share data across apps of the same publisher and data shared across multiple users of an app. You could save the data you want to pass to another app into the publisher folder and then in another app, you could access it too.
For more information, please refer to this blog: [Sharing your local app data](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/05/24/sharing-your-local-app-data/).

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't looked into sharing local app data.  Hm, it looks like that is sharing physical files which sounds slow for real time video :/  Maybe I'll stick to app services :)

Comment: Yeap, if your scenario is real-time video, that might not be suitable to use sharing local app data. Maybe app service is still the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

For large amount of data you can use [MemoryMappedFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/sharing-files-and-memory) to share data, don't forget to include `codeGeneration`capability in your manifest to be able to create MMF.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I ended up doing.  It was not easy, but eventually worked :)

Comment: Posting the difficulties you faced and how you got around it will be a good idea. This will make it easier for somebody else who tries this.